The number of ways $abcabcabc$ can be arranged so that no word contains the sequence $abc$
My approach is as follows: Total no. of permutations - abc appears once - twice - thrice
$For \ 1 \ abc \ : \ $  We can arrange $ \ a,b,c,a,b,c \ $  (in $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}$ ways),then subtract the cases where $abc$ appears atleast once, by taking $abc$ as a unit and then arranging $a,b,c,abc$ (it can be done in 4! ways). Atlast insert an $abc$. ei $$(\frac{6!}{2!2!2!} - 4!)\times {}^7C_1$$
$For \ 2 \ abc \ : \ $ Arrangement of $ \ abc,abc,a,b,c \ $ (in $\frac{5!}{2!}$ ways), subtracting the cases where $ \ abc \ $ occurs thrice (3 ways : $ \ a,b,c,abc,abc \ $ or $ \ abc,a,b,c,abc  \ $ or $ \ abc,abc,a,b,c \ $) ei. $$\frac{5!}{2!} -3$$
$For \ 3 \ abc \ : \ $ Only 1 way
Hence, Total no. of permutations - abc appears once - twice - thrice $$ =  (\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}  - ((\frac{6!}{2!2!2!} - 4!)\times {}^7C_1+(\frac{5!}{2!} -3)+1)$$ $$= 1160$$
Whereas the answer should be 1109. Where am i over/under counting cases ? Is there a better solution?

It seems like  the best way to do this is with Inclusion/Exclusion. Let $A$ be the set of all permutations of the lettters, and $A_i$ be the number of permutations where $abc$ starts at index $i,$ for $i=1,\dots,8.$ You want $A\setminus (A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_8).$ If course, $A_i\cap A_j$ is empty of $i\neq j$ and $|i-j|<3.$ And $A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k$ is empty if $i<j<k$ when $A_i\cap A_j$ is empty or $A_j\cap A_k$ is empty.

Is your word correct?  You have $9!$ in places, yet your word has $10$ characters.  It looks like you might have added an extra "a" by accident.

+1 : For showing a very detailed attempt to conquer the problem.  In judging the quality of your posted question, with respect to MathSE protocol, I regard it as irrelevant that your work has an analytical error, as indicated by the answer of Rupert Rybka.  I am therefore surprised that anyone would vote to close this question.

Since the answer of Rupert Rybka directly answers the original poster's question, I am going to expand on the comment of Thomas Andrews and provide an Inclusion-Exclusion answer.

See this article for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see this answer for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion formula.
Following the syntax in the 2nd link above, let $~S~$ denote the collection of all 9 character strings that contain 3 A's, 3 B's, and 3 C's.
For $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,7\},~$ let $~S_k~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ that specifically contains the sequence  ABC, starting in position $~k.~$  For example an element in $~S_1~$ would look like
A B C - - - - - -

where the string might or might not contain the sequence A B C after position 3.
Then, the desired enumeration is
$$| ~S ~| - | ~S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_7 ~|. \tag1 $$
Let $~T_0~$ denote $~| ~S ~|.$
Let $~T_1~$ denote $\displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq 7} | ~S_{i_1} ~|.$
That is, $~T_1~$ represents the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{7}{1} ~$ terms.
For $~r \in \{2,3,\cdots,7\},~$ 
let $~T_r~$ denote $\displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq 7} | ~S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap S_{i_r} ~|.$
That is, $~T_r~$ represents the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{7}{r} ~$ terms.
Then, in accordance with Inclusion-Exclusion theory, the computation in (1) above is equivalent to :
$$\sum_{r=0}^7 (-1)^r T_r.$$
So, the entire problem has been reduced to computing each of $~T_0, T_1, \cdots, T_r.$
As it turns out, this will be much easier than it looks.

$~T_0,~$ which denotes $~|S|~$ equals
$$\binom{9}{3} \times \binom{6}{3} \times \binom{3}{3} = 1680.$$
By considerations of symmetry,
$$T_1 = 7 \times | ~S_1 ~| = 7 \times \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{2} = 630.$$
That is, in $~S_1,~$ with A B C starting in position 1, from position 4 on, there are 2 A's, 2 B's, and 2 C's to be distributed.
At this point, I am going to postpone the computation of $~T_2,~$ which represents the most challenging computation in the problem.  Instead, I will now compute $~T_3, T_4, \cdots, T_7.~$
Then, in the next section, I will use a special method to compute $~T_2,~$ and in the final section, I will complete the problem.
There is only one way that you can have 3 of the sets $~S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_7~$ intersect.  That is with the string that specifically looks like
A  B  C  A  B  C  A  B  C

which represents $~S_1 \cap S_4 \cap S_7.$
So,
$$T_3 = 1.$$
By similar analysis, it is impossible to have a 9 character string that represents the intersections of $~4~$ or more of the $~S_1, ~S_2, ~\cdots, ~S_7 ~$ subsets.
Therefore,
$$0 = T_4 = T_5 = T_6 = T_7.$$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_2}$
$~T_2~$ could be computed manually.  I prefer to do it analytically, because the corresponding analysis will be generally useful.
As illustrative examples, consider the following tableaus
Tableau-1 : - - i-1 - - i-2 -
Tableau-2 : i-1 - - i-2 - - -

In Tableau-1 above, $~i_1~$ and $~i_2~$ are placed specifically in positions $~3~$ and $~6.~$  This specific tableau represents the $~S_3 \cap S_6~$ intersection.
In Tableau-1, the placement of $~i_1~$ and $~i_2~$ create $~3~$ islands: the island before $~i_1;~$ the island after $~i_1;~$ and the island after $~i_2.$  Let $~x_1, x_2, x_3,~$ denote the respective size of each of these islands, reading the islands from left to right.
Then, you have $~(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (2,2,1).~$
Now consider Tableau-2, which represents $~S_1 \cap S_4.$

The $~3~$ islands that it creates are $~(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (0,2,3).~$
Let $~N~$ denote the number of possible $~S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2}~$ intersections, that are consistent with the constraints of the problem.
Then,
$$T_2 = N \times \binom{3}{1} \times \binom{2}{1} \times \binom{1}{1} = 6N.$$
Stars and Bars theory can be used to compute $~N.$  For Stars and Bars theory, see
this article and
this article.
Each intersection represented by one of the terms used in the computation of $~T_2~$ is uniquely identified by its corresponding ordered triple $~(x_1, x_2, x_3).~$
$~N~$ will equal the number of solutions to

$~x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 7 - 2 = 5.~$ 
That is, there are $~7~$ positions, with $~2~$ of the positions taken by $~i_1~$ and $~i_2.$

$~x_1, x_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$~x_2 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$


The idea is that since $~S_{i_1}~$ represents a $~3~$ character string, the position of $~i_2~$ must be greater than or equal to $~(i_1 + 3).~$  This implies that $~x_2~$ must be $~\geq 2.$
Further, having $~x_1 = 0 ~$ merely represents that $~i_1 = 1,~$ which is perfectly acceptable.  Similarly, having $~x_3 = 0 ~$ merely represents that $~i_2 = 7,~$ which is also perfectly acceptable.
Basic Stars and Bars theory requires that each of the variables be an element in $~\Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.~$
This is easily achievable, via $~y_2 = x_2 - 2 \implies y_2 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
So, the enumeration of $~N~$ has been transformed into enumerating the number of solutions to

$x_1 + y_2 + x_3 = (7 - 2) - 2 = 3.$

$x_1,x_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$y_2 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$


By Stars and Bars theory:
$$N = \binom{3 + [3-1]}{3-1} = \binom{5}{2} = 10.$$
Therefore,
$$T_2 = 6N = 60.$$
Note
The (alternative) manual computation of $~N~$ would be to reason that for each $~i_1 \in \{1,2,3,4\},~$ there are $~(5 - i_1)~$ compatible positions for $~i_2.~$
Therefore, $~\displaystyle N = \sum_{i_1 = 1}^4 (5 - i_1) = 10.$

$\underline{\text{Completion of the Problem}}$
The desired enumeration is
$$\sum_{r=0}^{7} (-1)^r T_r$$
$$= ( ~T_0 + T_2 ~) - ( ~T_1 + T_3 ~)$$
$$= ( ~1680 + 60 ~) - ( ~630 + 1) = 1109.$$

I think the problem is with counting the number of ways for the case For 1 $abc$.
The problem is the fact, that when you plug your $abc$ in the end it can possibly land inside some other $abc$ in your subsequence, eventually making a correct sequence. For example:
$$
abccba \rightarrow a\color{red}{abc}bcbca
$$
But you missed that possibility in your approach.

Now what I have done is splitting this into some cases based on the location of our $abc$ in the sequence. I will focus of rearangements of remaining letters that form at least one more $abc$. Total number of ways to do so without that restriction is as you mentioned $\frac{6!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!}$.
Case $1$: $abc\_ \,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_$
Now we have, as you mentioned we have $abc, a, b ,c$ and we can arrange them in $4!$ ways, but we get two the same which are $abc, a, b ,c$ and $a, b, c, abc$ so we have: $\boxed{4! - 1}$ bad ways.
Case $2$: $\_abc \,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_$
Now we have to put $abc$ in the right part of this expression on $3$ ways  and arrange other letters in $3!$ ways (we can see that, they can't form another $abc$). In total we have $\boxed{3 \cdot 3!}$ bad ways.
Case $3$: $\_\,\_abc\_\,\_\,\_\,\_$
Similarly we have to put $abc$ in the right part of this expression on $2$ ways and arrange other letters in $3!$ ways. So in total we have $\boxed{2 \cdot 3!}$ bad ways.
Case $4$: $\_\,\_\,\_abc\_\,\_\,\_$
Now $abc$ will land either on left or the right side, and rearangement of remaining letters will give us $3!$ ways. But the is one way that we count twice which is $abcabcabc$ so in total we have $\boxed{2\cdot 3! - 1}$ bad ways.
There are $3$ remaining cases, which are symmetric to cases $1, 2$ and $3$ so we don't have to consider them separately.
Thus the number of sequences with just one $abc$ is:
$$
7\cdot \frac{6!}{2!\cdot 2!\cdot2!} - 2\cdot(4! - 1 + 3 \cdot 3! + 2 \cdot 3!) - (2\cdot 3! - 1) = 513
$$

Your calculations for other cases are correct and thus you get:
$$
\frac{9!}{3!\cdot3!\cdot3!} - (513 + \frac{5!}{2!} - 3 + 1) = 1109
$$

+1 : Very nice diagnosis of the original poster's work.

This answer is based upon the Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method. We consider the set of words of length $n\geq 0$ built from a ternary alphabet $\mathcal{V}=\{a,b,c\}$ and the set $$B=\{abc\}$$ of bad words, which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for. We derive a generating function $A(z)$ with the coefficient of $z^n$ being  the number of wanted words of length $n$. According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $A(z)$  is
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{A(z)=\frac{1}{1-dz-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=3$, the size of the alphabet and $\mathcal{C}$ is the weight-numerator of bad words with
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[abc])=-z^3\tag{2}
\end{align*}
We get from (1) and (2)
\begin{align*}
A(z)=\frac{1}{1-3z+z^3}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

Since we want to count the number of valid words of length $n=9$ which contain $3$ a's, $3$ b's and $3$ c's, we mark the generating function with the characters $a,b$ and $c$. We obtain according to (3)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{A(z;a,b,c)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-(a+b+c)z+abcz^3}}\tag{4}\\
&=1+(a+b+c)z+(a+b+c)^2z^2+\cdots\\
&\qquad+\left(a^9+9a^8b+9a^8c+\cdots+{\color{blue}{1\,109a^3b^3c^3}}\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\quad\left.+\cdots+(b+c)^9\right)z^9+\cdots
\end{align*}
where the last line was calculated with the help of Wolfram Alpha.

Result: The blue marked coefficient of $a^3b^3c^3z^{9}$  shows there are $\color{blue}{1\,109}$ words of length $9$ over the alphabet $\mathcal{V}$ built from $3$ a's, $3$ b's and $3$ c's which do not contain $abc$.

Add-on: With respect to a comment we show how to do the coefficient calculation manually. We use the coefficient of operator $[z^j]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^j$ of a series. We can so write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^j](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{j}
\end{align*}
We calculate the wanted coefficient $[a^3b^3c^3z^9]A(z;a,b,c)$ in a two-step approach by first calculating $[z^9]A(z;a,b,c)$ and then we calculate $[a^3b^3c^3]\left([z^9]A(z;a,b,c)\right)$.

First step: We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[z^9]}&\color{blue}{A(z;a,b,c)}=[z^9]\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z^j\left((a+b+c)-abcz^2\right)^j\tag{5.1}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^9[z^{9-j]}\left((a+b+c)-abcz^2\right)^j\tag{5.2}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^4[z^{8-2j]}\left((a+b+c)-abcz^2\right)^{2j+1}\tag{5.3}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^4[z^{8-2j}]\sum_{q=0}^{2j+1}\binom{2j+1}{q}(-abc)^qz^{2q}(a+b+c)^{2j+1-q}\tag{5.4}\\
&\color{blue}{=-\binom{3}{3}(abc)^3+\binom{5}{2}(abc)^2(a+b+c)^3}\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{-\binom{7}{1}(abc)(a+b+c)^6+\binom{9}{0}(a+b+c)^9}\tag{5.5}
\end{align*}

Comment:

In (5.1) we perform a geometric series expansion of (4).

In (5.2) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$ and set the upper limit of the series to $9$ since other terms do not contribute to $[z^{9-j}]$.

In (5.3) we note that we only need to consider even powers of $z$ due to $\left((a+b+c)-abc\color{blue}{z^2}\right)^j$. Therefore we take only odd $j$ which means $j\to 2j+1, 0\leq j\leq 4$.

In (5.4) we expand the binomial. We start the outer sum with $j=1$, since $j=0$ does not contribute.

In (5.5) we select the coefficient of $[z^{8-2j}]$.



Second step: We now extract the coefficient from $a^3b^3c^3$ in (5.5). We obtain
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{[a^3b^3c^3]\left([z^9]A(z;a,b,c)\right)}\\
&\quad=-\binom{3}{3}+\binom{5}{2}[abc](a+b+c)^3\\
&\quad\qquad-\binom{7}{1}[a^2b^2c^2](a+b+c)^6\\
&\quad\qquad+\binom{9}{0}[a^3b^3c^3](a+b+c)^9\tag{6.1}\\
&\qquad=-\binom{3}{3}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{1,1,1}-\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{2,2,2}\\
&\quad\qquad+\binom{9}{0}\binom{9}{3,3,3}\\
&\qquad=-1+10\cdot\frac{3!}{1!1!1!}-7\cdot\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}+1\cdot\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}\tag{6.2}\\
&\quad=-1+60-630+1680\\
&\quad\;\color{blue}{=1\,109}
\end{align*}
in accordance with the result from above.

Comment:

In (6.1) we already respect the factors $(abc)^q$ by applying the same rule as in (5.2).

In (6.2) we select the coefficient of $[a^qb^qc^q], 1\leq q\leq 3$ by using trinomial coefficients.



+1 to your answer.  Please keep in mind that I am totally uneducated in generating functions.  I like your approach, and think that it is good to indicate how generating functions can solve the problem.  This may motivate the original poster to learn generating functions.  I have one question that you may or may not regard as an overly difficult question to answer. ...see next comment

How hard would it be, to extend your approach to analytically compute the $~a^3b^3c^3~$ coefficient of $~1109 ~?~$ That is, I am wondering how difficult it would be to extend your work to derive a closed form expression for the $~a^3b^3c^3~$ coefficient.  Then, one might naturally use Wolfram Alpha, or the person's own computer program (perhaps in Java, C, or Python), to evaluate this closed form expression.  I am looking for something like $$\left[ ~a_1 \times \binom{n_1}{k_1} ~\right] +  \left[ ~a_2 \times \binom{n_2}{k_2} ~\right] + \cdots .$$

@user2661923: Not too hard. :-) I've added a manual derivation.
